# Do I need to replace water-damaged passport that has my valid visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports

I'm an Indian, soon travelling to the US for study on an F-1 visa. Recently, my passport got damaged in the rain and there is ink spread on the inside of the cover. The inside isn't damaged.

I went to my visa interview with this passport because it was just 2 day after the incident. They approved my visa and it was stamped in my passport.

However, friends have said that this could still be an issue during immigration checks. I leave in 35 days. What should I do?

Comment: Are all texts/stamps still legible?

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, they seem legible.

Comment: @Dorothy I started an application for a re-issue of passport and I'm facing the following problem -
My address on the damaged passport had a landmark written too. However, in my new application for passport, there's no option for landmark and there's a character limit on the address because of which I'm unable to add landmark. You mentioned that the data on both passports should be same - While everything else is the same, will the lack of landmark cause an issue or is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you replace a passport which is water damaged, as yours has, even though it contains a new and valid visa. Once that is accomplished, and the cancelled document is cancelled and returned to you, you can travel using both your new and the old passport which contains your valid visa. For your own reassurances, it might be wise to consult with your local US Consular officials, to determine whether the F-1 visa should be re-issued as a precaution.