# Should address match exactly when replacing damaged passport with valid visa?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

Recently, my passport was water damaged. I have my US F-1 visa in it. I saw in the answer to this question, [Do I need to replace water-damaged passport that has my valid visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96423/do-i-need-to-replace-water-damaged-passport-that-has-my-valid-visa?answertab=votes#tab-top) and the US Embassy confirmed that I need to replace the passport. However, the details need to remain the same as those in the damaged one.

While applying, I noticed that the address section now has a character limit and doesn't let me include the landmark that my damaged passport shows.

Will this be an issue when I arrive at US immigration and, if so, what should I do?

Comment: US passports don't even contain addresses. I doubt the US will care very much if an address in a foreign passport changes, let alone if the change is a truncation owing to a systems change.

Answer (score 2):

Such a very minor difference is not material change and will not affect your use of your visa when you arrive in the US. The details that are being compared are about you, and both the new and old biometric data will correspond. Don't worry; you've taken care to make sure that everything is in order and now all you have to do is to come to the US, enjoy your time, and be successful in your studies. With the diligence you've shown here, surely that will happen.